# Java Webapp with Map Features

Tags: java

I need to write a web-based application in Java with a "map" of our business campus. The user would then click on a building or location to annotate information about that location.

I cannot use Google Maps, I will have to upload an overhead photo as the basis for people to click on.

Can anyone make any recommendations about getting started?

Comment: Sadly, anything I could post would involve Google or Bing Maps.

Comment: I know. I figured out alot of the Google Maps API several years ago when I wrote some code to superimpose Census TIGER line data for counties over Google Maps to show county maps, then USGS geonames data to show features within that county.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by [ImageMaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) which map a region of your image to another URL which could be used to attach the information.

[Here](http://jimthatcher.com/webcourse5.htm) is a nice explanation on how to use it .
Instead of writing the coordinates by hand you would rather use a tool , see the [Image Map Editors Section](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Image_map_resources)